# Knapsack as a dynamic programming problem

Tags: linear-programming, np-complete, dynamic-programming

Ok so we are given the following linear programming problem:

$\max x_1 + 2x_2+2x_3+3x_4$

Subject to:

$2x_1 + 3x_2+x_3+2x_4 \le 4$

$1x_1 + 2x_2+ 3x_3+x_4 \le 4$

$x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4\in {0,1} $

My first thought is that this is an instance of the **Knapsack 0-1 problem** , but this 2nd constraint confuses me. From what i understand its like we have the weight of the items(for the 1st constraint) and in the 2nd constraint we have , lets say, the volume of every item , and that our backpack cannot contain more than 4 (happens to be the same as the weight).

Any ideas on how to approach this problem using dynamic programming?

Comment: Have you tried considering a two-dimensional state space in which the first component is the accumulated left hand side of the first constraint and the second component is the accumulated left hand side of the second constraint?  e.g. after stage 2, (5,3) would represent the solution $x_{1}=1$, $x_{2}=1$ and since $5>4$, you could cut-off consideration of solutions from this state.

Comment: can you explain this with a little more detail please?

Comment: The first constraint implies that $x_1+x_2\leqslant 1$ and $x_2+x_4\leqslant 1$, while the second constraint implies that $x_2+x_3\leqslant 1$. It follows that any solution in which $x_2=1$ has the other $x_i=0$. So if there is a feasible solution among $(x_1,x_3,x_4)$ with an objective value greater than $2$, we may omit $x_2$ from the problem.